# 親ウィンドウにフォーカスが当たっても子ウィンドウを表示し続ける方法は?

Tags: javascript

javascriptで、親ウィンドウからopenで子ウィンドウを開いた後、親ウィンドウにfocus()します。
このとき、子ウィンドウを前面に表示し続ける方法を探しています。
ブラウザはIE11です。

具体的には、子ウィンドウを開くときに、setTimeoutで3秒後に親ウィンドウにfocusしています。
このとき子ウィンドウはフォーカスを失うから、window.onblurかdocument.onfocusoutで
子ウィンドウにfocusすれば前面に表示し続けられると考えました。
それで、親ウィンドウと子ウィンドウを下記のようにしました。

親ウィンドウ(parent.html):

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openCF();">子ウィンドウを開く</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openCF() {
    open("./child.html", "_blank", 'width=200,height=200');

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.focus();
    },3000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

子ウィンドウ(child.html)：

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>子ウィンドウ</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.focus();    
    window.onblur = getFocus1;
    document.onfocusout = getFocus2;

    function getFocus1(){
        window.focus();
    }

    function getFocus2(){
        window.focus();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

これをIE11で実行すると、子ウィンドウを開いてから3秒後、予想に反して子ウィンドウは
親ウィンドウの後ろに隠れてしまいます。
ただし、子ウィンドウが前面に表示されているときに後ろの親ウィンドウを選択したときは、
子ウィンドウは隠れずに表示され続けます。
親ウィンドウにfocusしても子ウィンドウが隠れないようにすることはできないでしょうか?

**追記**

[window.openでモーダルぽくする - Qiita](http://qiita.com/bassyaroo/items/6566d06e27fdd970dc01)

上記URLを参考にして、一定時間ごとに子ウィンドウにフォーカスが当たっているかをチェックし、外れていたらフォーカスを当てるという処理にしてみました。
parent.htmlを下記のようにしました。

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openCF();">子ウィンドウを開く</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openCF() {
    var childWindow = open("./child.html", "_blank", 'width=200,height=200');

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.focus();
    },3000);

    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        // 子画面にフォーカスを当てる
        if(childWindow != null && !childWindow.document.hasFocus())
        {
            childWindow.focus();
        }
    },100);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

setIntervalを使って、子ウィンドウを0.1秒ごとにチェックし、フォーカスが当たっていなければfocus()します。

これで実行してみると、子ウィンドウにフォーカスを当てる処理は動いているようなのですが、それでも子ウィンドウは前面には来ませんでした。
フォーカスが当たっていることと、ウィンドウが最前面に表示されることは必ずしも一致しないのか、と思ってさらに調べています。

引き続き、ご回答いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 親画面ではユーザがどういう操作をすることを想定していますか？
例えば文字入力をするならば、勝手に小画面にフォーカスが移ってしまうと、まともに操作ができない状況が生まれてしまいますが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。親画面には子画面を表示するリンクが幾つかあるだけで、そのリンク押下以外は基本的に閲覧のみです。子画面も閲覧用ですが、子画面の方がコンテンツが多く、表示処理に時間がかかります。

Answer (score 1):

この手の動作はユーザビリティを損なうので年々ブラウザによる制限が厳しくなっています。
モバイルも増えてきた今、そもそも「ウィンドウ」を利用するのも良い方法ではありません。
ポップアップ表示などは、なるべく１タブ内で上手く行ってください。

Comment: この回答は質問に対する解決にはなっていません。回答がブラウザによる制限で「出来ない」のであればそのように回答された方が明確になると思います。単なる助言であればコメントで返信された方が良いかと思います。

Comment: 例えばウィンドウを一旦閉じて再び開き直すなど、実は調べれば幾つかのハック的な方法も見つかります。ですので、絶対に「出来ない」訳ではありませんし、ブラウザにもよります。ですが、その「無理やりで現在の流れに反する」方法がある事を教えてここに残すのは、しデメリットの方が多いと考えましたのでこのような回答になりました。つまり、「出来ない」と言うより「諦めて」「別の方法を見つけて」と伝えたかったのです。

Comment: 「このような事は考えずに諦めて別の方法を見つける事」が解ではいけないのでしょうか?下手に具体的な回答が付く可能性を残したまま放置するより、これは良くない考えという事を解として解決済みにするのが最も為になると考えたのですが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。可能だとしても良い方法ではないというのは理解できます。状況を説明させていただきますと、業務上ウィンドウを使わないということはできません。なるべく事情を単純化して質問させていただいていますが、問題になっているのはもっと複雑な環境です。できない、というのもクライアントに対する回答になりえるかもしれませんが、率直に言って取りたくない選択肢です。

Comment: @JSer はい、私もこの質問を解決するには強引な手法が必要であると考えますし、ユーザビリティを損なう動作にはなると思います。しかし、質問者のコメントも付いているように、様々な理由により、強引な手法を取らざるを得ないケースはあると思います。諦めて別の方法を見つけるというのは質問者への親切な助言ではありますが、この質問「親ウィンドウにフォーカスが当たっても子ウィンドウを表示し続ける方法は?」に対する回答（解決策）とは言えないと感じました。そのためコメントで誘導する方が適切ではないかと思い、先のコメントをつけた次第です。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。ただ一つ、私はこれがどうしても必要で避けられないという条件の質問ではなく、極めて良くないことだと分からないのだと思っていました。つまり、もし善悪の分からない子供が「どうしたら銀行強盗できるのか」と質問していたら、そこは無視せず「してはいけない」と回答すべきだと思ったのです。こういうときはまず、別の選択肢を取る余地が本当にないのかをコメントで確認するのが良いのかもしれませんね。

Comment: JSerさんのおっしゃる通り子ウィンドウの制御は時代の流れとともに難しい状況となってきています。もし親ウィンドウの描画領域内に子ウィンドウ（のようなもの）を描画すればよいのであれば親ウィンドウ内に`z-index`軸の最上位となるように子ウィンドウ相当の要素を表示するのがよいかと思います。子ウィンドウのコンテンツが多いとしてもAjaxやiframeなど、非同期にその表示内容を取得すれば初期表示の描画に時間がかかるということはありません。子ウィンドウを開いた後に親ウィンドウを閉じたり最小化したりする必要があるのであれば、やはりwindowとして実装する必要があるかとは思いますが、その解法は恐らくハック的（一時的）なものであり、今後のブラウザバージョンアップ等で制御不能に陥る可能性は低くないと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Windows を開いた側で 子 Windows にフォーカスをあてると目的の動作になると思ます。

`parent.html` の一部

```
function openCF() {
    var childWin = open("./child.html", "_blank", 'width=200,height=200');

    setTimeout(function(){
        childWin.focus();
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000)
    },3000);
}
```

サンプルは 定期的にフォーカスを当てていますが、子Windows の フォーカス状態を 子Windows の
`input[hidden]` な領域に設定しておき、その値を見て、フォーカスが外れているな。と判断できた時にフォーカスを当てるようにすると、もうすこし まともな動作になると思います。

---

ただ、この方法でも 親の IE が最小化されている時には子はフォーカスされません。
これは Windows API レベルで どうしようもない問題なのでこれを回避するためには
専用のプログラムを作成するしかありません。

[外部アプリケーションのウィンドウをフォーカスさせる方法](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/appactivate.html)

---

また、管理者権限で コマンドプロンプトを開いたり、リモートデスクトップ接続の場合などセキュリティー的に 特権が分離されたアプリケーションが存在する場合には それらのアプリが最優先となるため、思った通りには動かないと思います。
それは Windows である限りどうしようもありません。

Comment: 見直したら、追記の方法とほぼ同じですね。ただ調べるのは、ウィンドウのフォーカスか、そのイベントで設定する変数でしょうね。